# Self-host NancyFX REST Api is not access via Public IP on AWS EC2

Tags: .net, amazon-ec2, nancy, self-hosting, katana

Managed to host the NancyFX Api using `Katana - HttpListener (SelfHost)` but only the following url's are accessible from within the `EC2 host` (via RDP), which are tested via `Postman`:

- http://localhost:8786
- http://127.0.01:8786
- http://privateurl:8786

From outside the RDP (via client) the default IIS website is accessible on Port 80, but the self-host application is not accessible when I type the default website along with port (8786).

But, the REST Api is not accessible using `Public IP` or the `Public DNS`. I think, I need to configure the port but not sure what port do I need open. Am using `Amazon's Free Tier` so it is not possible to get support from Amazon. Hoping someone would help me here. I have been searching web but couldn't find an answer which solves my issue.

Under Security Group, I have opened the inbound flow see this screenshot.

[image]

Am i missing something else?

Comment: How have you registered the start options, can you share some code?

Comment: Have you opened up port 8786 on the firewall?

Comment: Have you run `netsh http add urlacl url=http://*:8786/ user=<your user>` to register the hostname with the port?

Comment: I have just executed the `netsh` but this doesn't seem to help.

Comment: By the way, I managed to stop the default website which was running at Port 80 and started my self-host app using Port 80, and all seems to work.